# Convert data file to Java static class constants for JUnit

Tags: java, xml, parsing, testing, junit

I had written few JUnit classes for my app, but I would like to now separate my test data (which is hardcoded now) from the code to a data-only text file/properties file/xml/whatever.

So I can easily give various test datas without modifying my JUnit.

I was thinking about putting them in a text file, and use a parser to parse it at the very beginning of my JUnit suite, and convert all of the data to a Java static class constants, so I can easily refer it anywhere in my JUnit.

```
public final class TestDataConstants {

public static final String username = "xbeta";
public static final String password = "test123!";
public static final String authToken = "f17bf9c8-9d38-47af-a053-210130cac6f7";
...
}
```

Now I know I can easily write a parser for this, but I'm asking 2 questions for people who had done this before in the past with experience

1. What format is the best and should be using for storing these test data?
2. What are some ways to convert these test data files to Java static class? Like generating Java code on-the-fly using Java.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use a .properties file and then load that in as a resource at the start of your test.

For example,

test.properties:

```
test.username=xbeta
test.password=test123!
test.authToken=f17bf9c8-9d38-47af-a053-210130cac6f7
```

Then in your tests you can access the data using something like the following, assuming the test.properties file is on your classpath:

```
// note, the .properties is removed in the call to .getBundle
ResourceBundle testProperties = ResourceBundle.getBundle("test"); 
String username = testProperties.getString("test.username");
String password = testProperties.getString("test.password");
```

Comment: Thanks.
But in this way, I would still need to hardcoded the fields such as "test.username".

I have arbitrary test data that could be anything.

Comment: @xbeta, in that case, even if you generate Java code, you can't refer to them via static constants, because some of the time they won't exist.

Comment: Yes, that's a valid point. What are some ways to tackle the issue in this case?

I thought about using [http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html), but I guess it won't help much in this paradox problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this with a `@DataProvider`, assuming that you put your data in a properties file:

```
public class A {

  @Test(dataProvider = "dp")
  public void test(String k, String v) {
    System.out.println("Testing " + k + " " + v);
    Assert.assertEquals(k.toUpperCase(), v);
  }

  @DataProvider
  public Object[][] dp() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.load(new FileInputStream(new File("/tmp/a.properties")));
    List<Object[]> result = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> es : p.entrySet()) {
      result.add(new Object[] { es.getKey(), es.getValue() });
    }
    return result.toArray(new Object[result.size()][]);
  }

  @Test(dataProvider = "dp")
  public void test(String k, String v) {
    System.out.println("Testing " + k + " " + v);
    Assert.assertEquals(k.toUpperCase(), v);
  }
}
```

The properties file:

```
abc: ABC
def: DEF
ghi: GHI
```

And the output:

```
Testing abc ABC
Testing def DEF
Testing ghi GHI
PASSED: test("abc", "ABC")
PASSED: test("def", "DEF")
PASSED: test("ghi", "GHI")

===============================================
    Test1
    Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Note that each set of parameter is passed to the test method (so the test method was invoked three times) and that this test method declared these as regular method parameters.

More details on data providers:  http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders

Comment: Thanks!

Is there a way to do this without TestNG? I meant I could be using this without having a Test Case and put into an Utilities class.

Thanks.